# Using process.env to pass vars from main process to preload script in Electron - Good option?

Tags: variables, process, electron, environment-variables, global

I'm working on a webapp wrapped with Electron and I'm trying to find an easy way to pass vars from **main process** to **preload.js** so I could later get it from my `BrowserWindow`.

I know we can use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to send/receive datas from main process to the renderer view but I found this way sometimes too complex for just getting simple data.

Also, I don't want to set the BrowserWindow `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` to **true** because this can be a crack for XSS attack such as [explained here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738).

I found a way (below) to pass vars from the main process to a `contextBridge` in the preload.js so I can later get these vars from the JS code of my `BrowserWindow`.

---

**index.js (MAIN PROCESS)**

```js
process.env.MY_SUPER_VAR = 'Hello'
```

---

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "electron", {
        mySuperVar : process.env.MY_SUPER_VAR
    });
```

---

**script.js (loaded later from page.html)**

```js
console.log(window.electron.mySuperVar);// 'Hello'
```

---

Is it a right way of doing it? Is it secure?
Any suggestions/advises/examples would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the one who posted [that comment](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738) you mentioned.

You *can* use `process.env`, but I'd recommend `process.argv` only for the reason that it's more in-line with the intended use of the property - (`env` is for environment-specific settings, `argv` are for application-specific settings), otherwise, they function in a similar enough way.

You can set `argv` values through the `additionalArguments` property on the [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window). As an example to refer to, I do this in my [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/app/electron/main.js) repository.

**Example**

```js
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: "Application is currently initializing...",
    webPreferences: {
      additionalArguments: [`--customValue=${value}`],
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
  });
```

In your **preload.js** file you can pull the value out and use it as you like.

```js
const arg = process.argv.filter(p => p.indexOf("--customValue=") >= 0)[0];
const argValue = arg.substr(arg.indexOf("=") + 1);
```

A word of caution, I'd recommend prefixing every element of `additionalArguments` with `--` in order to pass the value correctly and also *not include* any `\`, it [does not work when you do not follow these rules](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/32064).